# Avoid text-wrapping of code in Rmarkdown html output

Tags: html, css, r, markdown

I have been working on an Rmarkdown document to output as a html document. I'd like to stop it wrapping text in the code blocks. If I run a piece of code that makes something quite wide, it wraps the output, for example

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r, collapse = TRUE}
cbind(iris[1:3, 1:4], iris[1:3, ])
```
````

Returns (with point where it wraps depending on browser width obviously)

```
cbind(iris[1:3, 1:4], iris[1:3, ])
##   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Sepal.Length 
Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
## 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2          5.1          
3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2          4.9         
3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2          4.7
3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
```

**How can I specify that I want to turn of text wrapping in my code chunks?**

I've also got the CSS set up so that `.r{overflow-x: scroll;}` and tried things like `.r{max-width: 10000pt;}`, `{.r{white-space: ... }` with `normal`, `pre-wrap`, `pre-line`, `pre`, and `nowrap`, and some options in the Rmarkdown file (`options(width = 2000)` and `knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=2000),tidy=FALSE)` but no success.

Output should be that each row of my dataframe (or line of code etc) occupies only one line in the browser:

```
cbind(iris[1:3, 1:4], iris[1:3, ])
##   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
## 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
## 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: Hm. Putting `options(width=200)` inside the code chunk worked fine on my machine. At least when I viewed the document in the browser. In RStudio Viewer there was still some wrapping.

Comment: For me that changes the width of text that r assigns to each line, not the wrapping behaviour... I.e. `options(width=10)` would allow each line to occupy 10 characters, line one in the displayed code would be `cbind(iris`, line two `[1:3, 1:4]` etc.

Comment: Okay. I see. Sorry. Then I misunderstood what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: No, I think my example didn't illustrate it well enough... I've tried to modify it to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by adding style tags below the YAML header and overriding the existing CSS for pre and code:

```
pre {
  overflow-x: scroll
}

pre code {
  white-space: pre;
}
```